# What mistake did I make in 'TypeError'? And why does it show 'can be undefined' in the variable names in except section?

Tags: python, exception, typeerror, valueerror

```
try:
    day = int(input())
    month = int(input())

    if month == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    elif day > 31 or month > 12:
        raise ValueError
    elif type(day) != int() or type(month) != int():
        raise TypeError

except ZeroDivisionError:
    print(month, "is not a valid month")
except ValueError:
    if month > 12:
        print(month, 'is not a valid month')
    elif day > 31:
        print(day, 'is not a valid day of any month')
except TypeError:
    print("Please do not enter any string as input")

else:
    if day < 10:
        distance = 5 + (day * 2) / month
    else:
        distance = 3 + (day / month)
    print(distance, "Kilometres")
```

When I run it and input an invalid datatype variable, it doesn't raise the `TypeError`, but instead it shows a `ValueError`.
And in my code where the except part is started, PyCharm shows that my variables `'month'` and `'day'` are undefined.
What do I do?

Comment: What happens if you enter, say, `a` for the `day`?

Comment: That's because `int("some string which isn't all digits")` will `raise` a `ValueError`, not a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` always returns a string

`int()` casting will throw a `ValueError` for non-parsable input, otherwise, is always an `int` type.

Therefore, your `type()` checking is pointless (and you'd use `isinstance` anyway to check types).
If an exception is thrown by the `int()` calls, then one or both of `day` or `month` are never assigned, so cannot be used in the exception block without pre-declaring outside the `try`

e.g.

```
day = None
month = None

try:
  day = int(input())
  month = int(input())
except ValueError:
  if day is not None:
    # then the error is on the month
  else:
    # error on the day
```

I'd suggest defining your own `DateError` class for range validation